# Geocoder unable to get lat lng from particular string in android?

Tags: android, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am trying to get lat lng for the following address but geocoder is unable to find lat lng:

> Cascina Palazzetto n.9 - Strada Provinciale 134, POIRINO (TO) - 10046, Italia

and my code snippet is as follows:

```
public static LatLng getLocationFromAddress(Context context, String strAddress) {
  Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context);
  List<Address> address;
  LatLng p1 = null;
  try {
       address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
       if (address == null) {
           return null;
       }
       Address location = address.get(0);
       location.getLatitude();
       location.getLongitude();
     p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
  } catch (Exception ex) {
       Timber.d("getLocationFromAddress(printStackTrace): " + ex);
  }
  return p1;
}
```

Edit 1:

Also, I have tried with setting locale manually with Italy on geo coder but still I can't able to get results.

Comment: Yeah it's looks like working on REST API but don't know why not on android. 

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Cascina%20Palazzetto%20n.9%20-%20Strada%20Provinciale%20134,%20POIRINO%20(TO)%20-%2010046,%20Italia&sensor=false

Comment: Can you provide logs ?

Comment: The List object Address has size 0 rather that i am unable to get any information from log.

Comment: According to the best practices you should pass well formed address string and remove any additional info like business name etc.
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_queryformat

Comment: @xomena thank you for link but actually this same string provides lat and lng in ios and web which also using geo coder but android geocoder sdk doesn't return any value.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run loop for address list and when you get lat, long break loop.

Like,

```
  public static LatLng getLocationFromAddress(Context context, String strAddress) {
      Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context);
      List<Address> address;
      LatLng p1 = null;
      try {
           address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
           if (address == null) {
               return null;
           }

           for(int i=0;i<address.size();i++)
           {


           Address location = address.get(i);

           if(location.getLatitide!=0 && location.getLongitude!=0)
           {
                      location.getLatitude();
                      location.getLongitude();
                      p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),                      location.getLongitude());

                    break;
           }
       }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
           Timber.d("getLocationFromAddress(printStackTrace): " + ex);
      }
      return p1;
    }
```

Comment: but i am getting array size 0 so the scenario will be same.

Comment: Make size to 10 and try => address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 10);